# Set job plan by python script in maximo

Tags: maximo

How can i set a job plan into a workorder with python automatism scripting?
This is my code

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
woSet = MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet("WORKORDER", mbo.getUserInfo())
woSet.setWhere("WONUM='ODLSCAFF87'")
wo = woSet.getMbo()
mbo.setValue("JPNUM", "PDLSCAFF")
woSet.save()
```

But it doesn't work cause it doesn't find WORKORDER.JPNUM

Comment: Does the user running this script have access to the site of work order `ODLSCAFF87`? Can that user manually make the change in the UI? Are there any errors being thrown into the UI or logs?

Comment: Umm, shouldn't that be `wo.setValue("JPNUM".....`? Using your new "wo" MBO object instead of the old "mbo" MBO object (that is point to who knows what record type). I assume that is a error with typing it up for Stack Overflow?